# How do I find the mass of a sphere using proportionality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

A steel sphere 3.0 cm in diameter has a mass of 0.11 kg. What is the mass of a steel sphere 5.0 cm in diameter?

I know that $m= DV$ where D is density and V is Volume. I am assuming that both spheres have the same density since it is made of steel so I plugged in $1.5$ into $V=\dfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ and got $14.14cm^3$. I then plugged $14.14$ into $m= DV$ and got that the density was $0.0078$. Now I can solve for the unknown mass $m=0.0078(\dfrac{4}{3}\pi (2.5)^3)$. I got the mass is $0.51kg$. Did I do this problem correctly? If not could anyone explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

We are scaling **linear** dimensions (lengths) by the factor $\frac{5}{3}$.

If we scale linear dimensions by the factor $\lambda$, then volume is scaled by the factor $\lambda^3$.

So we are scaling **volume**, and therefore mass, by the factor $\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^3$.

The new mass is therefore $\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^3(0.11)$.

**Remark:** Your calculation was correct. More work, though!  And suppose that the item was not a ball, but a small statue of a horse, and we were scaling linear dimensions by the factor $\frac{5}{3}$. The scaling argument above would still work, but there is no "volume of a horse" formula.

Comment: So I did this problem correctly? :)

Comment: Yes, you did it correctly. You worked harder than necessary, but got the right answer by a correct method.

Answer (score 1):

You said you wanted an answer using proportionality. I'll work out the proportion with algebra, only substituting at the end.

m = DV and V = 4πr<sup>3</sup>/3, so m = 4πDr<sup>3</sup>/3

Now take the ratio of two masses:

m<sub>2</sub>/m<sub>1</sub> = (4πD<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub><sup>3</sup>/3)/(4πD<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub><sup>3</sup>/3)

Assuming they're the same kind of steel at the same ambient pressure and temperature, density is constant. This means D<sub>2</sub> = D<sub>1</sub>. Now simplify the right side by dividing the top and bottom by 4πD<sub>1</sub>/3:

m<sub>2</sub>/m<sub>1</sub> = r<sub>2</sub><sup>3</sup>/r<sub>1</sub><sup>3</sup>

Now solve for m<sub>2</sub> by multiplying both sides by m<sub>1</sub>:

m<sub>2</sub> = m<sub>1</sub> * r<sub>2</sub><sup>3</sup>/r<sub>1</sub><sup>3</sup>

Finally, substitute in m<sub>1</sub> = 0.11 kg, r<sub>1</sub> = 3.0 cm, and r<sub>2</sub> = 5.0 cm:

m<sub>2</sub> = 0.11 kg * (5.0 cm)<sup>3</sup>/(3.0 cm)<sup>3</sup> = 0.51 kg